# haproxy acl for url and url parameter

Tags: haproxy

I want to create an ACL in haproxy 1.6 that allows a particular url and url parameter ONLY when they both appear at the same time. For example:

```
example.com/url/of/page3?foo=bar
```

I am doing this already in the frontend section of my haproxy config:

```
acl whitelist path /url/of/page1
acl whitelist path /url/of/page2
acl whitelist path_beg /url/of/page3
block unless whitelist
```

How do I use [url_param](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.3.6-url_param) in combination with with [path](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.3.6-path) in my acl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Not sure which version you're running, but, just as a note: AFAIK, the `block` directive is deprecated. Using this, gives you:

> The 'block' directive is now deprecated in favor of 'http-request deny' which uses the exact same syntax. The rules are translated but support might disappear in a future version.

- It still works, but it might get removed in the future.
- Regarding your question:

  - Just set up another ACL:

    ```
    acl url_param urlp(foo) bar
    ```

    This tests the *first*, and only the first url param against the name `foo` and the value `bar`, and evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
  - So, after this, check for the results via:

    ```
    http-request deny unless whitelist url_param
    ```

Comment: Hello, how would you do this if you want to redirect `example.com/?foo=bar` to `example.com/my/app/?foo=bar`?